# Broken link on http://serverfault.com/tour

Tags: bug, status-completed

There is a broken link on the serverfault.com/tour page.

The link to [Product, service, or learning material recommendations](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa) gives me

```
Sorry, we can't find that page that you're looking for.

You could go back or visit the home page.

If you've just run into a broken link, please report it at our feedback site.
```

Comment: ok sorry. serverfault linked here. you are right. serverfault linked here and I wasn't aware that there is serverfault meta as well

Comment: I think this is the complete link: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ looks like something got chopped off.

Answer (score 3):

[This has been fixed](https://serverfault.com/tour).

For posterity: it's easy to find the intended target of a broken link [now that the blog is open-source](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/tree/master/_posts).